# Nothing happens in the try

Tags: android, json, arraylist, google-places-api

In this activity, i get places nearby and add them to a listview. I wanted also to add the place's phone number in an arrayList like the other datas, so i had to use place details request. So, i get all the place_id for all the places from the arrayList and launch the query to get the details (phone number). The problem is in class "**readFromGooglePlaceDetailsAPI**", it goes in the "**try**" and goes out with nothing happening, i don't know why!!! I only can see "IN TRY !!!" and then "----" from the println.

**Is my sequence not right?**

**Where is the problem and what is the solution ?**

```
public class ListActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

 public ArrayList<GetterSetter> myArrayList;
 ArrayList<GetterSetter> detailsArrayList;
    ListView myList;
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    TextView nodata;
    CustomAdapter adapter;
    GetterSetter addValues;
    GetterSetter addDetails;
    private LocationManager locMan;


@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.list_view_activity);

    if (!isNetworkAvailable()) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enable internet connection and RE-LAUNCH!!",
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return;
    }

    myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.placesList);

    placeSearch();


}

    private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null;
    }

 public void placeSearch() {

//get location manager
locMan = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
//get last location
Location lastLoc = locMan.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
double lat = lastLoc.getLatitude();
double lng = lastLoc.getLongitude();

    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Please wait", true);

//build places query string
String placesSearchStr;

placesSearchStr = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/" +
        "json?location="+lat+","+lng+
        "&radius=1000&sensor=true" +
        "&types="+ ServicesListActivity.types+
        "&key=My_KEY";

//execute query
new readFromGooglePlaceAPI().execute(placesSearchStr);

myList.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    }

public void detailsSearch() {
    String detailsSearchStr;

    //build places query string
    for(int i=0; i < myArrayList.size(); i++){

    detailsSearchStr = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?" +
            "placeid=" + myArrayList.get(i).getPlace_id() +
            "&key=My_KEY";

        Log.d("PlaceID:", myArrayList.get(i).getPlace_id());

    //execute query
        new readFromGooglePlaceDetailsAPI().execute(detailsSearchStr);

    }

}

public class readFromGooglePlaceDetailsAPI extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override protected String doInBackground(String... param) {
        return readJSON(param[0]);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String str) {

        detailsArrayList = new ArrayList<GetterSetter>();

        String phoneNumber =" -NA-";
        try {
            System.out.println("IN TRY !!!");

            JSONObject root = new JSONObject(str);
            JSONArray results = root.getJSONArray("result");
            System.out.println("Before FOR !!!");

            for (int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++) {

                System.out.println("IN FOR LOOP !!!");

                addDetails = new GetterSetter();

                JSONObject arrayItems = results.getJSONObject(i);

                if(!arrayItems.isNull("formatted_phone_number")){
                    phoneNumber = arrayItems.getString("formatted_phone_number");

                    Log.d("Phone Number  ", phoneNumber);
                }

                addDetails.setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
                System.out.println("ADDED !!!");

                detailsArrayList.add(addDetails);

                Log.d("Before", detailsArrayList.toString());

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        System.out
                .println("------------------------------------------------------------------");
        Log.d("After:", detailsArrayList.toString());
       // nodata = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nodata);
        //nodata.setVisibility(View.GONE);
       // adapter = new CustomAdapter(ListActivity.this, R.layout.list_row, detailsArrayList);
       // myList.setAdapter(adapter);
        //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
       // dialog.dismiss();


    }

}


public class readFromGooglePlaceAPI extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

  @Override protected String doInBackground(String... param) {
    return readJSON(param[0]);
}

protected void onPostExecute(String str) {
    myArrayList = new ArrayList<GetterSetter>();

    String rating=" -NA-";
    try {

        JSONObject root = new JSONObject(str);
        JSONArray results = root.getJSONArray("results");
        for (int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++) {


            addValues = new GetterSetter();

            JSONObject arrayItems = results.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONObject geometry = arrayItems.getJSONObject("geometry");
            JSONObject location = geometry.getJSONObject("location");
           //place ID for place details later
            String placeID = arrayItems.getString("place_id").toString();

            if(!arrayItems.isNull("rating")){
                rating = arrayItems.getString("rating");
            }
            addValues.setPlace_id(placeID);
            addValues.setLat(location.getString("lat"));
            addValues.setLon(location.getString("lng"));
            addValues.setName(arrayItems.getString("name").toString());
            addValues.setRating(rating);
            addValues.setVicinity(arrayItems.getString("vicinity").toString());

            myArrayList.add(addValues);

            //Log.d("Before", myArrayList.toString());


        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
  //  System.out
   //         .println("############################################################################");
  //  Log.d("After:", myArrayList.toString());
    nodata = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nodata);
    nodata.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    adapter = new CustomAdapter(ListActivity.this, R.layout.list_row, myArrayList);
    myList.setAdapter(adapter);
    //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    dialog.dismiss();

      detailsSearch();
}

}

public String readJSON(String URL) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URL);
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == 200) {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream content = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
            String line;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("JSON", "Couldn't find JSON file");
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

@Override public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    Intent details = new Intent(ListActivity.this, Details.class);
    details.putExtra("name", myArrayList.get(arg2).getName());
    details.putExtra("rating", myArrayList.get(arg2).getRating());
    details.putExtra("vicinity", myArrayList.get(arg2).getVicinity());
    details.putExtra("lat", myArrayList.get(arg2).getLat());
    details.putExtra("lon", myArrayList.get(arg2).getLon());
    details.putExtra("formatted_phone_number", detailsArrayList.get(arg2).getPhoneNumber());

    startActivity(details);
}

 }
```

Comment: Did you check your log outputs? Does readJSON properly finish?

Comment: It finishes well for the nearby request

Comment: Whats the error log!! plus made the code more readable and maintain code standard, For example Class name starts with a Capital

Comment: onPostExecute(String str) :  Print the string  str and paste here.

Comment: post try block code only there are multiple try blocks of code which is looks like more ..  so proper format your code

Comment: Problem is here: JSONArray results = root.getJSONArray("results");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try{
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(str);
    if (jsonObject.has("results")) {
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        //your logic here
        }
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: This will still throw the exception if `results` does not refer to a JSONArray.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the `getJSONArray()` function throws an Exception if the mapping fails. For example I can't find a JSON Array which is called `results`.

The most important thing you have to do at first is:

change:

```
catch (Exception e) {

}
```

to

```
catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(YOUR_TAG, "Exception ..." , e);
}
```

Your try throws an Exception which you don't even Log. That might be the reason why you are confused.

Comment: This line causes the problem, JSONArray results = root.getJSONArray("results");
You are right!

Comment: Happy to hear that. Your JSON is simply wrong. I guess we are done? Open up a new question if you have got further problems?!